# Synchronize allocation size with application and database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

I have declared allocationSize in entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "xxx_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "xxx_generator", sequenceName = "xxx_param_id_seq", allocationSize = 5)
private int id;
```

In database I created sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS xxx_param_id_seq INCREMENT BY 5;
```

But is it any mechanism to synchronize this two things?
For example when my application start It would set the same value which is in database or something like that.
I'm using hibernate in my application and postgres as database.
Have you some ideas about this mechanism?